# Spring Mvc DataSource Bean when using annotations

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I would like to know how **Dependency Injection** is done on the dataSource bean when using annotations in the applicationContext.xml or whats the annotation equivalent for injecting this bean into DAO's, i have the following dataSource bean defined:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: What persistence framework are you using?

Comment: I am not using any persistence framework just using spring no hibernate

Comment: so JDBC directly? ideally using the Templates available?

Comment: @MattWhipple yes just jdbc templates

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: Create a `SimpleJdbcTemplate` and inject it with the `DataSource`.  Then annotate that into your DAO:

```
@Repository
public class FooDao {
    @Resource(name = "jdbcTemplate")
    private SimpleJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
}
```

You're correct - you don't need anything more than `SimpleJdbcTemplate`.  Hibernate isn't necessary.

Comment: when u say create a SimpleJdbcTemplate you mean create a class with properties like driverClassName, url, username and password? If so would i need to hardcode the values for the attributes in there or i can still read it off the properties file?

Comment: No, you put them in your Spring configuration or a .properties file.  An even better idea, if you're using a Java EE app server, is to create a JNDI data source and refer to it by name.  Put the credentials on the app server.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should work.

@Resource
private DataSource dataSource;

or

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource

Comment: Do i leave the xml configurations as it is and just used these annotations or do i need to create a class with these values and then inject it?

Comment: Yes, leave the xml configuration as it is and use these annotation in the class you need to inject the datasource. You probably need <context:annotation-config/> in your xml, so spring will pick up these annotations.

Comment: I already have that i am using JdbcDaoSupport not the JdbcTemplate sorry for this error can you please advise since this uses - <object>= getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, parameters,new <Mapper()>);